# Продолжить выполнение кода, если нет ввода в input()

Tags: python

`input()` приостанавливает выполнение кода ожидая пользовательского ввода. А есть ли способ пропустить эту строку, если в течении X секунд `input()` так и не получил ввода?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Keyboard input with timeout in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335507/4279)

Comment: [решение для Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/4279)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import threading, time

def timeout_input(prompt: str, timeout: int):
    result = []
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: result.append(input(prompt)), daemon=True).start()

    t = time.time()
    while time.time()-t < timeout:
        time.sleep(.1)
        if len(result): return result[0]  # input result
    print('TimeoutError %s' % timeout)

a = timeout_input('enter a:', timeout=2)
b = timeout_input('enter b:', timeout=1)
print('a=%s b=%s' % (a, b))
```

out:

```
enter a:123
enter b:TimeoutError 1
a=123 b=None
```

Comment: Это плохое решение: оно оставляет `input()` вызовы весящими, что последующий ввод может испортить (не считая другие недостатки в реализации). Посмотрите на [решения в вопросе я сослался выше](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568893/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-input#comment745724_568893)

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing.pool

def input_timeout(text: str, timeout: int):
    return multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool().apply_async(input, [text]).get(timeout)
```

Comment: [это решение имеет ту же проблему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568893/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-input#comment746395_569065), что и использующее Thread напрямую